# How to convert an array into QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt4

I would like to convert an array into a QByteArray in Qt. Can someone explain the concept? Please provide an example.

Comment: Here(http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html) is some sample code and documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629534/c-hex-string-to-byte-array see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

`QByteArray` has a [constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-3) that does just this.

This is how to use it:

```
const char* data; int size; // these variables should be correctly set to your array and size
QByteArray ba(data, size);
```

I used a pointer for the data, but arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameters so it's the same. This constructor will make a deep copy of the data. That means it will only take ownership of the copy it makes, and the data you used might need to be deallocated if it was allocated dynamically.

For arrays of other types than `char` you are essentially doing serialization:

```
int data[30];

for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    ba.append((const char*)(data + i), sizeof(int));
}
```

The above code will insert the bytes that make up your ints into a `QByteArray`. Be careful though, since at this point indexing the `QByteArray` won't return the ints but the bytes they are made of.

To convert a [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html) (which is not what you asked but added a comment asking it) use one of the appropriate member functions of `QString`:

```
QByteArray ba = str.toLocal8bit();
QByteArray ba2 = str.toLatin1();
QByteArray ba3 = str.toUtf8();
QByteArray ba4 = str.toAscii();
```

To decide which one to use, you must know the encoding of your string. To convert between encodings, use [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextcodec.html#details)

Comment: In this solution you used the append method. Would the '+=' operator work just as well?

Answer (score 0):

An array of what?  Assuming you mean a null terminated char array:

```
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* myArray = "Hello World!";
    QByteArray myByteArray = QByteArray(myArray);
}
```

Comment: consider i am using.,      Qstring name = name[i]; then how could i convert it into Qbytearray??

Comment: @Naufal In your example `name` is an instance of the QString class, not a C++ array.

Comment: Actually, i am converting it to bytearray and then i want to convert it into qstring to get the image!!!!

Comment: @Naufal Converting **what**?!  You've failed to provide any code samples or, when I asked "An array of what?" answered the question.

Comment: sorry for that!!!!                                                QString Name = name[i];                                              QString Image = image[i];                                             ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(Image),f,ui->listWidgetexplore));
   I need to get the image!! where i have declared Image, but could not convert the string to QIcon,can you explain me!!!

Comment: @Naufal Please read '[How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)' before you post anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To store an array in QByteArray i've adapted method described here: http://smartqt.blogspot.ru/2014/05/how-to-convert-struct-in-and-from.html

My version for int array is

```
QByteArray serialize(int* ar, int ar_size)
{
    QByteArray result;
    QDataStream stream (&result, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream<<ar_size;

    for (int i=0; i<ar_size; i++)
        stream<<ar[i];

    return result;
}

void deserialize(const QByteArray& byteArray)
{
    QDataStream stream(byteArray);
    int ar_size=0;
    stream>>ar_size;    
    int* ar = new int[ar_size];

    for (int i=0; i<ar_size;i++)
        stream>>ar[i];
}
```

Cheers!